# Can I show Facebook posts/comments in ecommerce website search results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use the FB GraphAPI to call posts / comments using specific keywords so that this content can be shown on an e-commerce site search results page?

For example, a user on myhandbags.com searches for 'gucci handbags'. As well as the usual product search results, there is a tab for 'Social posts' - in this tab content from Facebook is shown that matches the search query 'gucci handbags' (so perhaps that phrase is contained in the post/comment).
So the site would need send a GET request to FB when the query is submitted and then fetch the relevant content and display it on the search results page.